# Error scatter plot time vs wind speed (data from a table) MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, scatter-plot, tabular

I am trying to make a simple scatter plot in MATLAB with time on the x-axis and wind speed on the y-axis. I loaded in my data from a text file as a table and then tried to use table2array to plot since it needs numeric values not table data. I also tried using double and got another error.

> Error Message: Error using scatter (line 55) Input arguments must be numeric or objects which can be converted to double.
>
> Error in windconversions (line 18) scatter(time,wnd_TS)

I'm not sure if having the times as strings will also be an issue.

```
T = readtable('allunderway.txt', 'HeaderLines', 2);
%A = table2array(T)

date = T(:,1);
time = T(:,2);
wnd_TD = T(:,10);
wnd_TS = T(:,11);
table2array(wnd_TS);
table2array(time);

%double(wnd_TS);
scatter(time,wnd_TS)
```

[image: data file]

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way to access the data contained within the table is to use the dot notation, as *T.VarN*, where N is the number of the column you are interested in.

In your code you are using only 'time' for the plot, however this consists of hours, minutes and seconds only. I suspect that for your graphical analysis you require the combination of both the date and the hours.

It is possible to perform arithmetic addition on datetimes, however it is required that the two variables have the same format. By converting both dates to format 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:SS' you are actually modifying the data of the variables. However, as stated in the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/combine-date-and-time-from-separate-variables.html):

> Since the data in the first column of the file ("date") have no time information, the time of the resulting datetime values default to midnight. Since the data in the second column of the file ("time") have no associated date, the date of the datetime values defaults to the current date.

When you add the variables date and time together together, you can add the date ('MM/dd/yyyy') of **date** to the time ('HH:mm:SS') of **time**.

An example of datetime conversion and addition follows.
Variables date and time before conversion:

```
date = 05/04/2011
time = 00:00:42
```

After conversion:

```
date = 05/04/2011 00:00:00
time = 06/01/2018 00:00:42
```

Adding the two:

```
05/04/2011 00:00:42
```

The code which reads the table and plots the scatter graph:

```
%Read table.
T = readtable('allunderway.txt', 'HeaderLines', 2);

%Access data of interest from table.
date = T.Var1;
time = T.Var2;
wnd_TS = T.Var11;

%Convert variable time to datetime.
time = datetime(time,'Format','HH:mm:SS');

%Add hours, minutes and seconds to variable date.
date = datetime(date,'Format','MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:SS');

%Add month, day and year to variable time.
time = datetime(time,'Format','MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:SS');

%Combine date and time variables.
fullt = date+timeofday(time);

scatter(fullt,wnd_TS);
```

The output of the code is the required scatter graph:

[image]

You can find more information on combining date and time from separate variables [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/combine-date-and-time-from-separate-variables.html).

Answer (score 0):

Why do so much extra work. You could have simply used `scatter(datenum(T.time),T.wnd_TS)`. That should do the job and save all the extra effort.